# Visual Studio 2008 macro to switch between header and source files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, shortcut

Does anyone know how to make a macro or something to switch between foo.hpp and foo.cpp? I would really appreciate having a macro like this. I guess it would help if it actually opened the corresponding file, but kept the old one in a tab.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps one (or a combination) of the following will help you:

- [Switch between a Header and a CPP File in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/h_cpp_switcher.aspx) (a macro at codeproject)
- [Switch between header and impl files in VS.NET](http://www.robertwrose.com/2005/06/switch-between-header-and-impl-files.html) (describes how to create the macro and bind it to a key)
- [Switch between Source and Header C++ Files](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/v-s/devstudio_macros/codenavigation/article.php/c14759) (A recent macro from codeguru)
- [Macro to Switch Between Header and CPP File](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/v-s/devstudio_macros/article.php/c3093) (An old macro from codeguru)
- **[Several other solutions found on Google...](http://www.google.com/search?q=visual%20studio%20macro%20switch%20header)**

Comment: I tested the 3rd suggestion in VS2008 and it works great. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: voted down because of the Google answer. It was completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use right click > Go to declaration | Go to definition?

Comment: Because if it's a macro, you can assign a keyboard shortcut to it, and that can be executed anywhere in the file. To use Go to Definition, the cursor would need to be over the class name.

Comment: Doesn't that help (take you right where you want to go)? Curious.

Comment: You might be working with more than .cpp and .h files. I have 'generator' files that auto create-add .cpp/.h/.cs/.whatever to VS, it is handy to be able to jump among them.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2013 it was added as Ctrl + K, Ctrl + O

Comment: Also available in VS 2015. The exact command is EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.ToggleHeaderCodeFile, [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx). I just figured out that [Menees VS Tools Extension](http://www.menees.com/VSTools.htm) 2015 adds a shortcut that collides with this.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the options ran slow for me in large projects. This one doesn't look in other folders but works faster and should cover most needs:
[switch between .cpp & .h files](http://www.alteridem.net/2008/02/26/visual-studio-macro-to-switch-between-cpp-and-h-files/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using 'Switch' - this is an addin that switches between source and header files, but also lets you switch between other types of related files - XAML and codebehind, designer and code etc etc. 
[Switch](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e50c0328-97a1-4842-8821-f0a82640245a)

Comment: Looks great, but it's no longer being maintained :(