# What is the VS2010 keyboard shortcut to show header file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a shortcut to move between header and source file in VC++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602682/is-there-a-shortcut-to-move-between-header-and-source-file-in-vc)

Hi.

Quick and easy question I haven't been able to discover myself:

Which is the keyboard shortcut for switching to the corresponding header file of a .cpp file in MS VS2010.

Thanks.

Comment: hmm isn't that a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602682/is-there-a-shortcut-to-move-between-header-and-source-file-in-vc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this functionality is available short of right-clicking in the CPP file and selecting "Go To Header" and from the header file selecting "Go To Definition" to switch back and forth.

Check out these similar questions for macros and addins to achieve a keyboard shortcut:

- [Visual Studio 2008 macro to switch between header and source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706938/visual-studio-2008-macro-to-switch-between-header-and-source-files)
- [Is there a shortcut to move between header and source file in VC++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602682/is-there-a-shortcut-to-move-between-header-and-source-file-in-vc)

You can also check out the [Visual Studio 2010 Keybinding Posters](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f&displaylang=en).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion of the keybinding posters. they are useful.